# HeapAlloc, HeapCreate Is garbage-collectable in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, memory-management, heap-memory

I have created a memory allocation library that can't be collected by GC. (https://github.com/10sa/Unmanaged-Memory)

The heap area allocated by this library is basically obtained by using the WinAPI GetProcessHeap() function. You can also create a heap area and assign it to it. However, the function used to create the heap area is the HeapCreate function.

Question is,

**1. Is this memory area (GetProcessHeap()) managed by GC?**

**2. If you create a new heap area using the HeapCreate function, can the generated heap area be collected by the GC?**

**3. If all of the above questions are true, How can I create a memory region in C # that is not collected without using Global Heap?**

Comment: May I ask what would be to reason to use unmanaged memory in CLR?

Comment: 1: No.  2: No.  3: imaginary problem.  Re-inventing Marshal.AllocHGlobal() is not useful.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek oh, there are *tons* of good reasons for that **in certain scenarios**; I doubt that OP is using any of those scenarios, though. I use it for GPU-enabled code where large numbers (10s of millions) of structs are treated as a chunk of unmanaged memory and shared between C# `unsafe` code and C CUDA kernerls; when .NET Core 2.1 lands, we'll also have `Span<byte>` / `Memory<byte>` allowing us to talk to unmanaged memory through 100% safe C# (the "100% safe" doesn't include the original allocation/assignment, note; but all subsequent access is safe)

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Just to learn. Or for someone else?

Comment: I think it is commendable to try to learn, but: the library shown is ... "not good"; it does a lot of unnecessary things that are already available within the CLR, and it doesn't fully do the things it *should* do (no finalizer, for example; the one case where you **must** use a finalizer is when you're dealing with unmanaged resources). It is also very suboptimal, not making use of either `unsafe` or `Span<T>` (very new) for access, and doing things like array copies; and it isn't clear *why* to use it. Just... please don't *use* that lib to do anything, at least: not in the current state.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I *do* understand there are usages of unmanaged memory in CLR. It's just that you should probably learn more about the whole platform stack so that you'd know whether `GetProcessHeap()` is managed before you try to implement your own library. You would also be much better aware of use-cases of your consumers and deliver APIs that help them do the right thing. Not to mention reliability. Check e.g. [Joe Duffy's blog](http://joeduffyblog.com/2005/12/27/never-write-a-finalizer-again-well-almost-never/) on some fun in-depth reads :) (the point is: doing this is hardcore)

Comment: If this is a learning experience, then I'm afraid, the lessons it'll teach you are rather disappointing. You'll learn, that using the managed CLR heap is often a lot faster, than any implementation of a heap manager over an unmanaged heap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. no; the clue is in the name ("unmanaged memory"), and in the fact that it is being allocated by the OS, not the CLR
2. no!
3. n/a

What are you trying to do here? There are already extensive inbuilt mechanisms for allocating unmanaged memory through the CLR without needing an external tool.

Additionally, in the examples: allocating 4 bytes in unmanaged memory is **terribly terribly** expensive and unnecessary. Usually when we talk about unmanaged memory we're talking about *slabs* of memory - huge chunks that we then sub-divide and partition internally via clever code.

Comment: How can i find that external tools?
P.s: why not?, I just want learning more!

Comment: @Tensa I don't want to sound rude, but promoting and publishing a library like this publicy without much knowledge is sort of a bad idea.

Comment: @Tensa I didn't mention external tools; but: `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` is probably all you need *if* unmanaged allocation is suitable for your scenario. None of your examples are **even remotely** suitable for unmanaged memory usage.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks to your answer. :)

Comment: Hmm, HeapAlloc() does not suck that bad.  It is used in C and C++ code to implement malloc() and new.  It was made to sub-divide large allocations.  VirtualAlloc() is the hog.

Comment: @HansPassant Wait, that mean allocated memory is can be freed by C++ "delete" Keyword? (or free())

Comment: Since VS2012, yes.  Prior versions of the CRT used HeapCreate to create its own private heap.  The delete operator isn't safe, it expects a destructor.

Answer (score 0):

In Win32/Win64 and C/C++ the Heap API were a godsend, allowing any amount of temporary allocation, with all allocations from the custom heap being freed in a single call.  They are likely unnecessary in .NET.

Allow me some skepticism for Microsoft's advice on good practices.  I remember a division meeting where we were told that memory leaks are an inescapable fact of life.